# Control laser pointer on/off from external switch

Tags: control, laser, laser-diode

I want to hook up leads to a laser pointer so that I can control it using an external switch. The goal is to turn the laser on/off using a MOSFET connected to an Arduino.

The battery contacts are integral to the device, so physically tricky to connect wires to. If anyone has done something like this before, I'd love to see how you did it.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this. Do you have access to anything internal? Does it have to maintain the same form factor? Does it need to be portable? As it stands this question is too broad to know what would constitute a "good" answer.

Comment: Use a shutter maybe?

Comment: You could buy a laser pointer with TTL control or a separate laser diode driver with modulation in for so little money it's probably worth buying a product that does this by design.

Comment: How about an AC relay?

Comment: This is a question about how to mechanically connect wires to the pointer, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the battery part of the pointer, and attach your wires there directly to the body, and to the spring. Next- you need to hold the push-button spring permanently down using whatever method you need. I used a small piece of pior section, put a hole in it centered on the PB and screwed a flat point screw into that.

I use something similar as a star pointer attached to my telescope as a "finder"

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't indicate the size of the battery or how it is connected.

Depending upon the size and shape of the battery, you could either:

- carve a fake battery from wood (or 3D print it in plastic) and attach metal contacts and wires to it leading to a switch and power supply.
- insert a piece of paper between the battery and the top contact, with aluminum foil glued to either side of the paper and wires leading to a switch.

Comment: There are ready-made so-called "battery dummies" for that kind of thing.  Some may be without cable, just a "0V" battery for mixing with Li batteries in a pack intended for NiMH or Alkaline.  No idea whether one can tap such a 0V battery or whether its poles are connected too solidly.